# Python-flask: Get different datas from multiple rows by request.form.get() method

Tags: python, html, flask

I used Python with flask web framework.
I have a web page with 3 rows (or it can be less or more) with server names which can be updated by users. You can see page layout in the attachment.
[page layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzJUO.png)

I am using a for loop inside html code, to get lines to fill according to hostnames and host number. The code is:

```
...
<table class="table table-hover">

          <tbody>
            {% for h in todos_host %}
            <tr class="thead-dark">
                <th scope="row" width="30%">Check link: {{ h.hostname }}</th>
                <td width="70%"><input class="form-control" name="checklink" type="text" placeholder="ex. http://xxxx"></td>

            </tr>
            {% endfor %}


          </tbody>
       </table>
...
```

End user will put different data in fields marked with "ex. http://xxxx" placeholder.
In my main script i am trying to get the value of rows with request.form.get('checklink') but this one gets only first value (for gerenbach server). How can I use this method with loop in order to get each row's value ?

Comment: you cannot use the same name for each input, you should use a different way to indentify each one. You can use `name="checklink{{ loop.index }}"` and then call `request.form.get('checklink1')` , `request.form.get('checklink2')`... but this pattern is not so clear with multiple rows. The best may be to build `todos_host` differently, as a list of dicts for example, with a clear key to match each host. Please post your view if you need more help

Comment: Thank you @PRMoureu
I am now able to get data from different fields but now updating database is a problem. when I insert data into DB either same data is written in or only last column is updated. I think, as you said, it is better to change todos_host data type. I will try...